# Linq to get the data from 2 columns having same name of 2 different tables using "Joins" in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

1. This is my method where I emplement the autocomplete-:

```
public async Task<List<string>> EmailSearch(string filter)
        {
            try
            {
                var x = await _context.tbl_Account.Where(x => x.Email.Contains(filter) && x.IsActive == true).Select(x => x.Email).ToListAsync();
                return x;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

2. In the above code I was getting the data from one table but now I want data from another table also using "Joins" with Linq for condition like in above code, in .NET Core.
3. The table names are tbl_Account and tbl_Contacts both table have a column which is named as Email (same column name).

-> Thanks in advance...

Comment: TRy : var results = from a in  _context.tbl_Account join c in _context.tbl_Contacts on a.Email equal c.Email select new {account = a, contact = c}).ToList();

Comment: [LINQ only supports equality joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause), there's not a way to use a different operator in the `join` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You create two queries and then union them, since you're just using a string as a result, you should be ok, try something like this...

```
public async Task<List<string>> EmailSearch(string filter)
    {
        try
        {
            var x = _context.tbl_Account
                    .Where(x => x.Email.Contains(filter) && x.IsActive == true)
                    .Select(x => x.Email);
            var y = _context.tbl_Contacts
                    .Where(x => x.Email.Contains(filter) && x.IsActive == true)
                    .Select(x => x.Email);

            var z = await x.Union(y).ToListAsync()
            return z;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```